# How can i communicate beetween python scripts over the public internet?

Tags: python, network-programming, chat

I'm trying to create the usual basic chat app that everyone knows.
But there's a catch, even after reading similar questions here and watchin videos on youtube, i realized that the Socket module is made for this. Even after trying though, i cannot find a way to communicate over the public internet. Here's what i tried:

- using my public ip, not the local one, on both server and client
- using my public ip on the client and 0.0.0.0 as the server one
- using an instance of ngrok and using its ip and port, but python will say:

  OSError: [WinError 10049] Address not valid in your context

Thanks for your time.
If anyone could help i'll appreciate example code

Comment: Are you hosting these on a normal domestic internet connection? You are likely to find that your domestic router doesn't allow you to listen on a port in the way that your script would require unless you can enable port forwarding? The easiest way, for sure, would be to use an API for an existing messaging service, such as telegram.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis port forwarding may cost money? anyhow there is this website https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ that allows hosting and running python code in cloud (also for free (with limitation obvs)), (could make some basic flask app for the communication and then ping that server for updates and stuff or maybe can manage sockets on there too, don't know much in detail, just that it exists)

Comment: For my ISP I can setup port forwarding on the router itself, no need to pay the ISP any more, although there would usually be an additional cost if you wanted a static IP. Good to know about python anywhere!

Comment: @Matiiss sorry, cannot host my server in the cloud, in needs to be on my pc for external reasons that are too long to write on this comment.

Comment: @giocoacose you can use cloud as a proxy between your computer and the other computer, so basically your computer first sends to the server, then the server sends to the other computer, that way for example info that is on your computer can be sent first to the cloud then the other computer can ping the server and get the info

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for the advice, i tried pythonanywhere.com, but i don't see any way to be able to connects public sockets to that

Comment: @giocoacose ok, well I don't know how to do that either, another option would be to use `flask` and create a website that allows chatting (on pythonanywhere), but I guess that is not what you want, also can't the `sockets` connect to urls? or at least `sockets` maybe could convert the url and then connect? somehow, maybe you can try doing this thing I have only heard about but the idea was to use a linux server on google drive or sth like that, also don't you kinda need a static ip anyways, for server connections like this, if you wanted to use your own router, besides port forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

This question was PARTIALLY solved by myself after 3 hours of searching. Hope this can be a good example on how to do this. I'm hosting ther SERVER instance on an amazon ec2 instance, for how to do this exactly continue reading.

On amazon aws, create an ec2 instance with "Amazon Linux" image.
The basic, lowest, worst plan is actually enough. 2virtual cpus and 0.5 gigs of ram. once you created it, in the section "security groups" add the following inbound rules:

a "custom tcp" rule, enter the port you wish to use in the socket code, and use as origin "0.0.0.0/0";
another custom tcp rule, with the same port, but with origin "::/0"; an SSH rule, if not already there, with origin "0.0.0.0/0".

in the server, write the following code:

```
IP = socket.gethostbyaddr('aws_instance_public_ip')[0]
PORT = 34758

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((IP, PORT))
s.listen()
```

in the client, write the following code:

```
s = socket.socket()

IP = 'aws_instance_public_ip'
PORT = 34758

s.connect((IP, PORT))
```

notes:
i'm using python 3.7; you need to replace the aws_instance_public_ip with the actual ip of the instance, you cannot leave it like this. This code **DOES NOT WORK** if i host the server in my computer. It raises an error, but if you can fix please post a reply, thanks.